# Why swagger request url using proxy name?

Tags: nginx, swagger

I am testing RESTful API using swagger2. This is my NginX config:

```
location / {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://envelop-microservice;
        index index.html index.htm;
}
```

When I invoke API in swagger, the swagger2 request URL command like this:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'appCode: 101'  'http://envelop-microservice/room/type/list'
```

Why the URL using proxy settings not the domain? How should I configure to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line on you nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

config on your nginx would like this:

```
location / {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host; # add this line
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://envelop-microservice;
        index index.html index.htm;
}
```